# How do one object Categories Induce Monoids?

Tags: category-theory

From pg. 11 of *Categories for the Working Mathematician*:

> *Monoids.* A monoid is a category with one object. Each monoid is thus determined by the set of all of its arrows, by the identity arrow, and by the rule for the composition of arrows. **Since any two arrows have a composite, a monoid may then be described as a set $M$ with a binary operation $M \times M \rightarrow M$ which is asociative and has an identity (= unit).**

**Question:** I do not see how we go from arrows $\rightarrow$ on a category with one object to a monoid $M$, which makes use of the notion of $\times$ (as described in the quote). So how exactly do categories with one object induce monoids (in the algebraic sense of the word)? Or, how do we move from $\rightarrow$ to $\times$ as expressed in the quote?

Comment: $M$ is the set of arrows, the map $M\times M \to M$ is composition of arrows...

Comment: The definition of category makes use of $\times$ too: composition is a family of functions $\hom(B,C) \times \hom(A,B) \to \hom(A,C)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be more helpful to first see how any given *monoid* (in the usual sense) can be turned into a *category.*

Suppose $\mathcal{M}=(M, *, e)$ is a monoid. Then we consider the following category $\hat{\mathcal{M}}$:

- $\hat{\mathcal{M}}$ has one object, $\alpha$.
- $\hat{\mathcal{M}}$ has one arrow $f_m$ for every $m\in M$.
- The composition law in $\hat{\mathcal{M}}$ is given by $$f_m\circ f_n=f_{m*n}.$$ (Note that in particular this makes $f_e=id_\alpha$.)

You can think of $\alpha$ as representing the set $M$, and $f_m$ as representing the map $x\mapsto mx$; but you can also just think of the abstract data above as standing on its own.

---

The construction described in your post is just the dual of this: from an appropriate category, we can construct a corresponding monoid.

Answer (score 0):

Give a one-object category, define the corresponding monoid as follows: The underlying set of the monoid is the set of the arrows of the category. The product of two arrows $f$ and $g$ is the composite $gf$, which always exists because the category has only one object. Composition in a category is associative by definition, and one of the arrows in the set of arrows must be the unique identity arrow of the only object, so the resulting structure is a monoid.

Note that this works for small categories.  For a large category you get a "large monoid".